# Autodesk Maya 2014 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, 64-bit

I had Maya 2014 installed on my ubuntu machine and this runs like a charm. As of 10th february the service pack 4 is available i decided to update maya to the latest recent version EXT SP4.

Maya crashes now on opening with a segmentation fault.

`/usr/autodesk/maya2014-x64/bin/maya2014
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
maya encountered a fatal error
Signal: 11 (Unknown Signal)
Stack trace:
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x364a0) [0x7fe5fcb2c4a0]
  jpeg_CreateDecompress
  /usr/autodesk/maya2014-x64/qt-plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so(+0x39d7) [0x7fe5e3f589d7]
  /usr/autodesk/maya2014-x64/qt-plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so(+0x56e7) [0x7fe5e3f5a6e7]
  /usr/autodesk/maya2014-x64/qt-plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so(+0x576c) [0x7fe5e3f5a76c]
  QImageReader::read(QImage*)
  QImageReader::read()
  QPixmapData::fromFile(QString const&, char const*, QFlags<Qt::ImageConversionFlag>)
  QPixmap::load(QString const&, char const*, QFlags<Qt::ImageConversionFlag>)
  QPixmap::QPixmap(QString const&, char const*, QFlags<Qt::ImageConversionFlag>)
  QmayaQtHelper::createPixmapFromPath(Tstring&)
  QmayaQtHelper::createPixmap(Tstring&)
  QmayaIconTextControl::createIconPixmap(QString const&)
  QmayaIconTextControl::setIcon(QString const&, int, bool, bool)
  TelfIconTextBaseCmd::doEditFlags()
  TelfIconTextButtonCmd::doEditFlags()
  TshelfButtonCmd::doEditFlags()
  TiceBaseCmd::doCreate()
  TiceBaseCmd::doCommand(TargList&)
  Mel_Command_Dispatch(SphNode*)
  node_exec
  fc_if
  node_exec
  f_function_entry_node
  node_exec
  sophia_call_executable
  SophiaExecutable::evaluate(void*)
  TcommandEngine::sourceFile(Tstring const&)
  TmayaModuleSupport::loadModuleScripts(Tstring const&)
  loadModuleScriptsAtMayaInit
  /usr/autodesk/maya2014-x64/bin/maya.bin() [0x40dd48]
  /usr/autodesk/maya2014-x64/bin/maya.bin() [0x4153fa]
  Tapplication::start()
  /usr/autodesk/maya2014-x64/bin/maya.bin() [0x40f936]
  main
  __libc_start_main
  /usr/autodesk/maya2014-x64/bin/maya.bin() [0x40c1f9]`

For me it seems libc related but im not sure. Maybe someone could help here a little step

Of course i exported my nvidia path to make sure maya can see my nvidia libs. This is how start it:

```
env HOME=/home/user/maya env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-331 env LC_NUMERIC="C" /usr/autodesk/maya2014-x64/bin/maya2014
```

Any kind of help would be very usefull as it worked before i updated to SP4. Well i have to say that i not converted the .rpm based packages to .deb. I extracted the content of the SP4 maya*.rpm and copied it over my installation path.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall it and re-install maya sp1 from known sh.files provided on the internet after finishing install download maya 2014 sp4 and extract it and convert rpm to deb after that by start clicking on Debian file it will open it software center and click on re-install button in Maya2014_64-2014.0-986.x86_64 the software center will show upgrade button  are   maya SP4 will be ready to work after activating